# October CMS Plugin Routes.php not registering

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

OctoberCMS Specific Problem,

When declaring routes in the {my}/{plugin}/Routes.php file they work on my local development environment which is a laravel Homestead Box. When I push it up to my production environment a Laravel-Forge provisioned (similar to homestead), it fails to register plugin routes.

There is the exact same code base on local & dev where I ran artisan route:list.

```
(LOCAL)vagrant@homestead:~/default$ php artisan route:list
| Method   | URI                 | Action                                              |
|----------|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|
| GET|HEAD | chg/api/email/index | Chg\Email\Http\Controllers\ReferralController@index |
| POST     | chg/api/email/send  | Chg\Email\Http\Controllers\ReferralController@send  |
| GET|HEAD | index_eli           | Closure                                             |

(REMOTE)forge@personal:~/default$ php artisan route:list
| Method   | URI         |      | Action  |
|----------|-------------|------|---------|
| GET|HEAD | sitemap.xml |      | Closure |
```

Here are my plugins Routes.php file

```
<?php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'chg/api/email/'], function() {
    Route::get('index', 'Chg\Email\Http\Controllers\ReferralController@index');
    Route::post('send', 'Chg\Email\Http\Controllers\ReferralController@send');
});
Route::get('index_eli', function (){
    return 'hello';
});
```

I want to point out that if I were to register a route under modules/cms/routes.php it works both locally and remotely.

besides the generic 404 page not found error I am not getting any errors. So my question is has anyone seen this before? and do they know where to look to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is mention in your first line `{my}/{plugin}/Routes.php`, **R** is capital it must be lower case for Linux system.

Its case sensitive issue, please change `Routes.php` to  `routes.php` and it will work.

Linux treat Routes.php and routes.php as separate files and octoberCMS/Laravel look for routes.php not Routes.php

Comment: Yes .. October CMS is case sensitive.  I have one question can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124069/send-email-using-october-cms